# IDE launcher script (idea.sh) is outdated Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android-studio

I get this message when android studio 3.0.1 starts.

```
IDE launcher script (idea.sh) is outdated. Please upgrade, otherwise you won't be able to restart the IDE.
```

note: i have just updated AS from 2.3.3 to 3.0.1 
my OS is Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: How did you upgrade? Did you delete this file, then install?

Comment: no i didn't delete any thing .. i used : sudo java -classpath AI-162.4069837-171.4443003-patch-unix.jar com.intellij.updater.Runner install android-studio

Comment: Is that command documented somewhere? I doubt that upgrades the shell script, only the IDE

Comment: my OS is Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: That's not what I asked, but okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same thing. My mistake was probably after downloading the new version to the location the previous version was, I just reran the Ubuntu menu item which uses the updated version + the old private folder in my case `~/.AndroidStudio1.5`.

The solution was:

1. Delete the menu item (in my case in `.local/share/applications/jetbrains-studio.desktop`)
2. `cd` into Android Studio `bin/` folder
3. Start Android Studio: `./studio.sh`

The problem should be gone.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Update your java environment to 1.8 something (latest version).If any doubt plz ask me...Explaination...In android studio press ctrl+shift+A, 'Enter action' window will appear,Type 'Switch IDE boot JDK' and select latest version.

Comment: you mean jdk ??

Comment: yes latest jdk 1.8 or java 7. You can also use embedded jdk comes with android studio 2.2 and higher.

Comment: i actually have jdk 1.8 ,, but i am on linux machine . this warning appeared after i pinned android studio to task bar . i even notice that when i hover on AS icon in the task bar a title of another project shows up instead of the title of currently opened project.

Comment: type java -version. it will give you java version. i have 1.8.0_151(latest java 8). when u restart android studio it also gives u switch option.Click on switch.Then select java latest version.